# Change staff height in Musescore

Tags: musescore

Using Musescore, I often print off music and find the staff height is a little small for my liking. Is there a way to change the staff height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Home › Handbook › Formatting › Layout and formatting](http://musescore.org/en/handbook/layout-and-formatting).

You'll be looking at Layout / Page Settings. The parameter you're looking for is Scaling / Space. The short explanation beneath the illustration will make clear why.